# Select the UITableView on UICollectionView selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a `UICollectionView` inside `UITableViewCell`. When I select the a `tableView` row, I do not want the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` method of `UICollectionView` to get called. Instead I want `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method of `UITableView` to get called. How would I call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: plese first try make collectionview selection none

Comment: Are the cells of collection view selectable? I mean do u need these cells of collection view to be selectable

Comment: I do not want them selectable, but I want them scrollable. I tried disabling the userInteraction of collectionView. On selection, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is ultimately called, but, collectionView isn't scrolling

Comment: @iOS : If you are disabling the user interaction of collectionView, it will stop scrolling. Any sort of interaction with the collection view is not possible then. So disabling the user interaction is not an option.

Comment: @PulkitSharma : That was a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `collectionView.allowsSelection = NO` to disable selection.

OR in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method, grab the UITableViewCell and call the delegate which is the table view that has UITableView:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *parentCell = collectionView.superview;
    [parentCell.delegate collectionViewDidSelectedAtCell:parentCell];
}
// IN your view controller that has the table view

- (void)collectionViewDidSelectedAtCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell{
     NSIndexPath *index = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
     [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:index];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

Comment: How come, it should disable selection of collection view. Are you still receiving `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` ?

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3

First set the following

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let parentCell: QMatrixCell? = collectionView.superview?.superview as! QMatrixCell?
    parentCell?.delegate.collectionViewDidSelectedAtCell(cell: parentCell!)
}
```

and in the controller that contains your tableview do the following

```
extension TableViewController: SelectionCell{
 func collectionViewDidSelectedAtCell(cell : QMatrixCell){
    let index: IndexPath? = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAt: index!);
 }
} 
protocol SelectionCell {
   func collectionViewDidSelectedAtCell(cell : QMatrixCell);
}
```

and don't forget to set delegate in your tableView cell.