# fetch & update UITableView cells from a collectionView cell click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, closures

Say, I have a ViewControllerA with a `tableView`, and that `tableView` has its header view created and loaded using `xib` method, and that headerView contains a `.horizontal` scroll direction collectionView, my question is how would I update the contents of my `tableView` on click initiated by the `collectionView` inside the headerView?

similar example is in the below picture:
[image]

say, I clicked the "Research" label on the `UICollectionViewCell` inside the Tableview's HeaderView and the tableView reloads data of "Research", and next I clicked the "Design" label, and the tableView reloads the itself and displays data for "Design".. something like that is possible? i am stuck here.. .

Comment: A simple approach to handle this is by using the delegate pattern

Comment: well, since i am stuck here, could you please suggest one, if you can?

Comment: how would you go about it if you happen to do it?

Comment: You can go with the pure collection view and using view layouts but it's too complex to implement

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552625/uicollectionview-inside-uitableviewcell-how-to-set-the-selection-to-pass-data-fr and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35448927/select-the-uitableview-on-uicollectionview-selection

Comment: you already asked this question and answered your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

link the header `UICollectionView` to an outlet in the storyboard, then implement all the required delegate methods.
Add this delegate method:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

var categories = [String]()
var discoverData = [discoverModel]()
var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    categories.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //code to initialize cells of header collecionView
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedCategory = categories[indexPath.row]
    let cellToReload = discoverData.filter{return $0.serviceName == selectedCategory}[0]
    
    guard let indexPathsOfCellToRealod = discoverData.firstIndex(of: cellToReload) else { return }
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(index: indexPathsOfCellToRealod)], with: .automatic)
}
}

struct discoverModel: Equatable{
   var image: UIImage
   var serviceName: String
   var name: String
   var description: String
}
```

To make this work, just add the standard `UITableView` delegate methods to your ViewController